# Bash using source to load config file

Tags: bash, sh

I need to use a configuration file (which simply has some variable settings) which will be used by the sh script. I'm using source to do it, like so:

cmd.config file:

```
CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME=
JAVA_FLAGS=-server -Xmx2048M
```

program.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "cmd.config" ]; then
    source "cmd.config"
fi

[ -z "$CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_BIN="java" || JAVA_BIN="$CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME""/bin/java"
```

The idea is to load the file only if it exists and then use those variables.

However I always get:

> xxxx@ubuntu:~/Desktop/program$ ./program.sh live
>   ./program.sh: 3: ./program.sh: source: not found

then the program starts using the defaults (cmd.config is not loaded).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `.` instead of `source`. See: [. (source or dot operator)](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html).

Comment: unrelated to your question, but the proper syntax for combining a variable name with a string is `${var}string`, i.e., `JAVA_BIN="${CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"`

Comment: Your question is tagged `bash`, but the script uses `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. `/bin/sh` is often a link to a shell other than `bash`, and even when it links to `bash` it disables most extensions.

Comment: @Barmar oh I don't know much about this. Should I use `/bin/bash` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is a `bash` extension. If you want to use `bash` syntax, you need to start the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Or you could use `.` instead of `source` to execute the script, this is portable to all POSIX-conforming shells.

Also, the config file needs to use the correct syntax to set shell variables. The line:

```
JAVA_FLAGS=-server -Xmx2048M
```

tries to execute a command named `-Xmx2048M` while setting the environment variable `JAVA_FLAGS=-server`. To make the whole thing the value of the variable, it needs to be quoted:

```
JAVA_FLAGS='-server -Xmx2048M'
```

And if these are supposed to be environment variables rather than just shell variables, you need to export them:

```
export JAVA_FLAGS
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the changes. Still no luck. I used `#!/bin/bash`, then enclosed `JAVA_FLAGS` in quotes, but the export I didn't use. These are variables that are being used to run a command. the end of the script looks like: `$JAVA_BIN  -classpath com.class.blah `

Comment: How is `$JAVA_FLAGS` being used?

Comment: Seems like its loading the file as now I'm getting a `/bin/java/: No such file or directory`. But the variable seems empty or something is wrong in this line: `[ -z "$CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_BIN="java" || JAVA_BIN="${CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"`.

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so you can see the commands as they're executing.

Answer (score 0):

`source` function cannot load a standard file, you need to make the file a system file by adding `.` in front of the file name.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f ".cmd.config" ]; then
    source ".cmd.config"
fi

[ -z "$CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_BIN="java" || JAVA_BIN="$CUSTOM_JAVA_HOME""/bin/java"
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. I don't get the error, but the variables in the config are not set.

Comment: @FedeE. `JAVA_FLAGS=-server -Xmx2048M` is not the correct syntax, you need quotes around the value.

Comment: @Barmar I did that change. Still not working. Seems that the cmd.config is not being loaded.

Comment: @Barmar if you run `source .cmd.config` and then `echo $JAVA_FLAGS` what does it print?

Comment: `source` and `.` are identical, but `source` is a Bashism.

Comment: @BenjaminW. FreeBSD/OpenBSD seems to be on a different page with that. If the file doesn't contain `.` prefix, it won't load the config on boot. My old Mac and my FreeRADIUS server that's built on Unix-like have this problem. So my bad if I gave the invalid information.

Comment: I think there are two things at play here: while booting, the shell being used is probably not Bash, so you'd have to use `.` and not `source`. Then, in your code, you use `/bin/sh` but `source` - and `source` is a Bashism, but you're not using Bash. I don't think prepending `.` to a file has anything to do with whether you can source it or not.